# How to automatically add the Application to Team / Chat / Group Chat & The bot is not part of the conversation roster

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Application is adding to the Personal chat/Group Chat but if I'm doing Submit action(**microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask**) I'm getting error like **The bot is not part of the conversation roster** So every time in group chat section adding this application manually to make this application work., So how can I make this dynamically so can you please help me out on this issue.,
Please find the image below for your reference [image: Image-1]

Thanks

[image: manually adding application to Group chat]

Answer (score -1):

It's currently not possible to do this - as you've identified, there is no Graph endpoint to add a bot to a Group chat, only personal and Teams channels as of now.

Documentation reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages#proactive-app-installation-in-teams

You can raise your voice over here:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new